# Can REST in practice really be stateless?

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs

Consider the situation.

I am writing a statistical analysis app. The app has multiple tiers.

1. Frontend UI written for multiple device types, desktop, browser,
   mobile.
2. Mid-tier servlet that offers a so-called REST service to
   these frontend.
3. Backend that performs the extreme computation of the statistical
   processing.
4. Which communicates with a further backend database

Due to the reason that statistical analysis requires huge amount of processing power, you would never dream of delegating such processing to the front-end.

1. The statistical analyses consists of procedures or a series of
   work-flow steps.
2. Some steps may require so much processing power, you would not want
   to repeat them.
3. If you have a work-flow of 20 steps, you cannot execute step 20
   without first executing step 19, which cannot be executed without
   first executing step 18, so on and so forth.
4. There are observation points, such that, for example, the
   statistician must inspect results of steps 3, 7, 9, 14, 19 before
   telling to client-side to proceed to the next step.
5. Each of these steps are a so-called request to the REST service, to
   tell the backend supercomputer to progressively set up the
   statistical model in memory.
6. There are many workflows. Some workflows may incidentally share step
   results. e.g., Flow[dry]:Step[7] may share Flow[wet]:Step[10]. Due
   to the amount of processing involved, we absolutely have prevent
   repeating a step that might incidentally have already be
   accomplished by another flow.

Therefore, you can see that in the so-called REST service being designed, 
it is not possible that each request be independent of any previous request.

Therefore, how true can the following statement be?

> All REST interactions are stateless. That is, each request contains
>   all of the information necessary for a connector to understand the
>   request, independent of any requests that may have preceded it.

Obviously, the application I described, requires that request be dependent on previous request. There are three possibilities that I can see concerning this app.

- My app does not comply to REST, since it cannot comply to stateless requests. It may use the JAX-RS framework, but using JAX-RS and all the trappings of REST does not make it REST, simply because it fails the stateless criteria.
- My app is badly designed - I should disregard trying to avoid the temporal and financial cost restacking up a statistical model even if it took 5 - 15 minutes for a workflow. Just make sure there is no dependence on previous requests. Repeat costly steps when necessary.
- The stateless criteria is outdated. My understanding of REST is outdated/defective in that REST community have been constantly ignoring this criteria.

Is my app considered RESTful?

**New Question:  ISO 9000**

Finally, in case my app is not completely considered RESTFul, would all references to "REST" need to be omitted to pass ISO 9000 certification?

new edit:

**REST-in-piece**

OK, my colleague and I have discussed this and decided to call such an architecture/pattern REST-in-piece = REST in piecemeal stages.

Comment: what's your definition of a "state"?

Comment: Dmitry - exactly my question. We have to ask the gurus who define REST.

Comment: a database contains state yet there are a lot of database backed web applications that are considered RESTful.   What if the database or part of it is in memory?  Basically, I believe that the "state" that the ReST architecture shouldn't maintain is a session (volatile) state, not the application (business) state.

Comment: The mathematical models in memory are volatile.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

ISTM, you're reading too much into to statelessness.  A REST API supports traditional [CRUD operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).  The API for [CouchDB](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=4&ved=0CEYQtwIwAw&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bfje5csISQ8&ei=C1_YTtOVGMrKiQLKpOmPCg&usg=AFQjCNGZRlj5ulFXW1gEnRDnE9K3Q1w0UA) is good example of how DB state is updated by a series of stateless transactions.

Your task is to identify what the resources are and the "state transfers" between them.  Each step in your workflow is a different state transfer, marked by a different URI.  Each update/change to a resource has an accompanying POST/PATCH or an idempotent PUT or DELETE operation.

If you want to gain a better of understanding of what is means to be RESTful and the reasons behind each design choice, I recommend spending a hour reading [Chapter 5 of Roy Fielding's Dissertation](http://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/rest_arch_style.htm).

When making design choices, just think about what the principles of RESTful design are trying to accomplish.  Setup your design so that queries are safe (don't change state) and that they are done in a ways that can be bookmarkable, cacheable, distributable, etc.  Let each step in the workflow jump to a new state with a distinct URI so that a user can back-up, branch out different ways, etc.  The whole idea is to create a scalable, flexible design.

Comment: I wish you to tell me if the stateless criteria holds water anymore. Yes/No? Is my understanding of statelessness defective? Yes/No. If so, explain RESTful statelessness.

Comment: Before asking this question, I had exactly been reading that chapter.

Answer (score 2):

You are updating an in memory model via a REST api. This means that you are maintaining state on the server between requests.

The REST-ful way of addressing this would be to make the client maintain the state by simply processing the request and returning all the information for constructing the next request in the response. The server then reconstructs the in memory model from the information in the request and then does its thing. That way, if you operate in a e.g. a clustered environment, any of the available servers would be able to handle the request.

Whether or not this is the most efficient way to do things depends on your application. There are loads of enterprise applications that use a server side session and elaborate load balancing to ensure that clients always use the same nodes in a cluster. So having server side state is an entirely valid design choice and there are plenty of ways of implementing this robustly. However, server side state generally complicates scaling out and REST in the purest sense is all about avoiding server side state and avoiding complexity.

A workaround/compromise is persisting the state in some kind of database or store. That way your nodes can fetch the state from disk before processing a request.

It all depends on what you need and what is acceptable for you. As the previous commenter mentioned, don't get too hung up on this whole stateful-ness thing. Clearly somebody will have to maintain state and the question is merely what the best place is to put that state for you and how you access it. Basically there are a couple of tradeoffs that basically have to do with various what-if type scenarios. For example, if the server crashes, do you want your client to re-run the entire set of requests to reconstruct the calculation or do you prefer to simply resend the last request? I can imagine that you don't really need high availability here and don't mind the low risk that something occasionally goes wrong for your clients. In that case, having the state on the server side in memory is an acceptable solution.

Assuming your server holds the computation state in some hash map, a REST-ful way of passing the state around then could be simply sending back the key for the model in the response. That's a perfectly REST-ful API and you can change the implementation to persist the state or do something else without changing the API when needed. And this is the main point of being REST-ful: decouple the implementation details from the API. Your client doesn't need to know where you put the state or how you store it. All it needs is a resource representation of that state that can be manipulated.

Of course the key should be represented as a URI. I recommend you read Jim Webber's "REST in practice". It's a great introduction to designing REST-ful APIs.

Comment: Should my app incur the cost of unloading the mathematical model from the memory of the supercomputer into a database, just to satisfy statelessness criteria?

Comment: No, unless losing state when your server dies is a problem for you I wouldn't do anything like that. If not, all you need to do is try to think of your model as a resource that you make available via http and that you can do PUT,POST,GET, and DELETE requests on.